# Hover flip cards using Reactjs and styled-components all rotating at once

Tags: reactjs, hover, styled-components

Disregard the mess, this is my first project using Reactjs.

I created some cards displaying images of Star Wars characters and when hovered they'll flip and display information about said character.

Unfortunately, whenever I hover one, the card adjacent to it will also rotate.

I know the issue is I have the onMouseEnter essentially applying to all at once however, I'm unsure on how to fix or adjust this problem.

```
return (
<CardContainer>
  {loading && <h1 className="loading">LOADING...</h1>}
  {characters.map((character, result) => {
    return (
      <Card id={result}
        onMouseEnter={() => setFlip(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setFlip(false)}
      >
        <CardFront flip={flip}>
          <CardContent>
         
            <CardImage img={characterToProfileImage[character.name]} />
          </CardContent>
          <BGFade />
        </CardFront>
        <CardBack flip={flip}>
          <CardContent>
            <h1 className="info-name">{character.name} </h1>
            <h2 className="info-text">Height: {character.height}cm </h2>
            <h2 className="info-text">Weight: {character.mass}kg </h2>
            <h2 className="info-text">Gender: {character.gender} </h2>
            <h2 className="info-text">Eye color: {character.eye_color} </h2>
            <h2 className="info-text">
              Birth year: {character.birth_year}
            </h2>
          </CardContent>
        </CardBack>
      </Card>
    );
  })}
</CardContainer>
```

You can check the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-leaf-1mqdud?file=/
and the file in question is components/Characters.js

Comment: You need to change your `flip` state to be an array instead of a single value.

Comment: You can use this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-sara-nkux89?file=/src/components/Characters.js) for reference.